# waitFor unable to find HTML element after setTimeout and advanceTimersByTime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that utilises quite a few setTimeouts in order to do three things: a) mount a child to the DOM, b) animate that child in, c) unmount that child after user interaction.

I'm trying to mock this behaviour in a test, and am specifically testing step b - I'm doing a `queryByText` to grab the text value of the child that I animate in.

However, the text never seems to show up in the HTML that gets printed to the CLI when the test fails. The error is as follows:

```sh
expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has value: null
```

My test looks like this:

```js
it("should show message after setTimeout", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
    const amendedMockContext = {
      ...baseMockContext,
      introductionData: {
        data: {
          cta: "This is a cta!",
        },
      },
    };
    customRender(<FAB />, { contextProps: amendedMockContext });
    const message = screen.queryByText(/this/i);
    await waitFor(() => expect(message).toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

and my component animates in and out like so. Note the `$visible` flag triggers the animation:

```js
const CTA_REVEAL_TIME = 5000;

export default function FAB() {
  const [showCTA, setShowCTA] = useState(false);
  const [mountCTA, setMountCTA] = useState(false);

  // mount just before animating (step a)
  useEffect(() => {
    const mountCTATimer = setTimeout(
      () => setMountCTA(true),
      CTA_REVEAL_TIME - 1000
    );
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(mountCTATimer);
    };
  }, []);

  // animate in message (step b)
  useEffect(() => {
    const CTATimer = setTimeout(
      () => setShowCTA((prevState) => !prevState),
      CTA_REVEAL_TIME
    );
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(CTATimer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {mountCta && <p $visible={showCTA}>{message}</p>}
    </>
  );
}
```

In my test, I've tried using various methods of async/await, `waitFor`, all the different query/get/find methods, but can't seem to get it to actually await the message revealing, even though I'm artificially advaning time by 5000ms. I also use `advanceTimersBytime` in other tests and have no such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should mount the component first, then advance the timers.

```
import { act, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import FAB from './FAB';

describe('71867883', () => {
  it('should show message after setTimeout', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    render(<FAB />);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
    })
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText(/this/i)).toBeInTheDocument());
  });
});
```